# Android : place views along circle in a layout at runtime

Tags: android

What i want to do is place view along circle whose center is a parent layout.

I tried my best, I can't see anything. Below is my code.(alphabetView is just simple extends from textview. for debugging purpose i commented placing along circle,and change it to placing along simple line)

When i placed it at a constructor, i couldn't get width and height, but i could see child views. so far as i know, i can only get 0 width and height in constructor. So I moved code to onSizeChanged. 
But now, after place it on onSizeChanged, i could get center of parent layout, but i can't see any child. 
Am i misunderstand something? Is there any better way to achieve placing view along ring?

```
public class RingUIView extends RelativeLayout {
    private String[] _keySet = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
    private double UI_SIZE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        float centerX = getX() + getWidth() / 2;
        float centerY = getY() + getHeight() / 2;

        Log.e("ASDF", String.format("%f, %f", centerX, centerY));
        double radian = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _keySet.length; i++) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alphabet_view, null);
            AlphabetView alphabetView = (AlphabetView) view;
            alphabetView.setText(_keySet[i]);
            this.addView(alphabetView);
            /*float childX = (float)(centerX+UI_SIZE*Math.cos(radian) - alphabetView.getWidth());
            float childY = (float)(centerY+UI_SIZE*Math.sin(radian) - alphabetView.getHeight());*/
            float childX = centerX + 20 * i;
            float childY = centerY + 20 * i;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.leftMargin = (int) childX;
            params.topMargin = (int) childY;
            radian += Math.PI / 4;
        }

    }

    public RingUIView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing this in onLayout? look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Comment: @Raanan i've just tried onLayout. But there were no difference

Comment: Try adding the views in the constructor and changing their Params in the onSizeChanged